# Paginação ASP.NET MVC PagedListPager com mais de um parâmetro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho a seguinte pagina usando x.PagedList

```
@using AspNet.Models;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc

@{

ViewBag.Title = "Visualiza";
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<AspNet.Models.Pessoa>

}

<h2>Pessoas Cadastradas</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-inverse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Idade</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Setor</th>
            <th>Sub Setor</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Pessoa pessoa in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@pessoa.nome</td>
                <td>@pessoa.idade</td>
                <td>@pessoa.usuario</td>
                <td>@pessoa.setor</td>
                <td>@pessoa.sub_setor</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edita", "Pessoa", new { 
 @id_pessoa = pessoa.id_pessoa }, null)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
  Página @Model.PageNumber de @Model.PageCount
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Visualiza","Pessoa", new 
  {pagina = page}) + "&setor=" + ViewBag.setor)
```

Perceba que no URL.Action acima estou passando dois parametros GET, o pagina e o setor... quando a pagina é gerada, ele gera certinho o link do get:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando vou pra pagina 2 e quero voltar para 1, ele perde o get setor: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Ja consegui fazer.. eu estava espeficicando a action errada... o correto seria  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("VisualizaPorSetor","Pessoa", new 
  {pagina = page}) + "&setor=" + ViewBag.setor)

Comment: Responde a sua pergunta com essa resposta para documentar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui fazer. Eu estava especificando a `Action` errada. O correto seria:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("VisualizaPorSetor","Pessoa", new {pagina = page}) + "&setor=" + ViewBag.setor)
```